# Neo4j James Bond

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been playing around with the James Bond dataset in Neo4J graphgist and using Neo4J Bloom I want to find the different cars in a particular Movie but I dont know how to search for it. As it is now I get all cars in all movies.
What would be the proper Cypher code for retrieving all the cars in a specific movie?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the cypher query you've tried, issues you're running into, input data, expected vs actual output, etc. As written, this is too broad: you've only provided a high level requirement, and no Cypher query (or data).

Answer (score 0):

I got this from the web.

List all vehicle brands in Bond movie and its appeared model

```
 MATCH (m:Film)-[:HAS_VEHICLE]->(v:Vehicle)
 RETURN DISTINCT v.Brand AS Brand, count(v.Model) AS 
 Models, collect(DISTINCT m.Name) AS Movies
 ORDER BY count(v.Model) DESC
```

https://neo4j.com/graphgists/know-more-about-james-bond-movie/